# Form in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, forms

I am looking for a way to simply create a form in Objective-C. I tried to build one using a table view, but this one does not handle the return key correctly and does not look very apple-like. Is there a "right way" to do this?

[image]

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?

Comment: Down votes on questions are free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table view is the best control for this. Create a custom cell with UITextField. Handle return key in you UITextField.